# Parse Json with javascript with for loop

Tags: jquery, json

I am new to javascript and looking to do a for each loop on the below sample JSON string. I am trying to loop through each result item and see if the name = 'Error Code'. I have tried multiple different variations and the below snippet seems like it is correct but i cannot get it to show up in the console.

```
            $.ajax({
                 url:'url',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function (data) {
                      //handle the json response

                     for(let i = 0, l = data.results.length; i < l; i++) {

                         if (data.results.variable[i] == 'Error Code'){
                             console.log(data.results.value[i]);
                         }

                        }
                },

            });
```

```html
    {
  "Count": 136,
  "Message": "Results returned successfully.",
  "SearchCriteria": "VIN:xxxxxxx",
  "Results": [
    {
      "Value": "",
      "ValueId": "",
      "Variable": "Suggested VIN",
      "VariableId": 142
    },
    {
      "Value": "0",
      "ValueId": "0",
      "Variable": "Error Code",
      "VariableId": 143
    },
    {
      "Value": "",
      "ValueId": "",
      "Variable": "Possible Values",
      "VariableId": 144
    },
    {
      "Value": null,
      "ValueId": "",
      "Variable": "Additional Error Text",
      "VariableId": 156
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors on the code you presented:

1. Your data has `Results`, `Variable` and `Value` (and other properties also), all of them with uppercase first letter, and in your code you are trying to access it with lowercase (e.g: `data.results`), so it is undefined (Javascript is a case-sensitive language), it must be `data.Results`.
2. Also, you are looping through `Results`, not `Variable`, so the `[i]` goes after `Results`, like this: `data.Results[i].Variable`

see below

```js
var data = {
  "Count": 136,
  "Message": "Results returned successfully.",
  "SearchCriteria": "VIN:xxxxxxx",
  "Results": [{
      "Value": "",
      "ValueId": "",
      "Variable": "Suggested VIN",
      "VariableId": 142
    },
    {
      "Value": "0",
      "ValueId": "0",
      "Variable": "Error Code",
      "VariableId": 143
    },
    {
      "Value": "",
      "ValueId": "",
      "Variable": "Possible Values",
      "VariableId": 144
    },
    {
      "Value": null,
      "ValueId": "",
      "Variable": "Additional Error Text",
      "VariableId": 156
    }
  ]
}


for (let i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
  if (data.Results[i].Variable == 'Error Code') {
    console.log(data.Results[i].Value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help

```js
 var data = {
  "Count": 136,
  "Message": "Results returned successfully.",
  "SearchCriteria": "VIN:xxxxxxx",
  "Results": [
    {
      "Value": "",
      "ValueId": "",
      "Variable": "Suggested VIN",
      "VariableId": 142
    },
    {
      "Value": "0",
      "ValueId": "0",
      "Variable": "Error Code",
      "VariableId": 143
    },
    {
      "Value": "",
      "ValueId": "",
      "Variable": "Possible Values",
      "VariableId": 144
    },
    {
      "Value": null,
      "ValueId": "",
      "Variable": "Additional Error Text",
      "VariableId": 156
    }
  ]
}
data.Results.forEach(item => {
if(item.Variable === 'Error Code') console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that JS is case-sensitive. This means that `data.results` is not the same as `data.Results` and will cause problems.

With regard to your question, you don't need an explicit loop here. Assuming there's only ever one object containing the `Error Code` string then you can use the `find()` method to retrieve it:

```
var error = data.Results.find(o => o.Variable === 'Error Code');
```

```js
var data = {
  "Count": 136,
  "Message": "Results returned successfully.",
  "SearchCriteria": "VIN:xxxxxxx",
  "Results": [{
      "Value": "",
      "ValueId": "",
      "Variable": "Suggested VIN",
      "VariableId": 142
    },
    {
      "Value": "0",
      "ValueId": "0",
      "Variable": "Error Code",
      "VariableId": 143
    },
    {
      "Value": "",
      "ValueId": "",
      "Variable": "Possible Values",
      "VariableId": 144
    },
    {
      "Value": null,
      "ValueId": "",
      "Variable": "Additional Error Text",
      "VariableId": 156
    }
  ]
}

var error = data.Results.find(o => o.Variable === 'Error Code');
console.log(error);
```

If there may be multiple elements with the same `Variable` value, then you can use `filter()` instead:

```
var errors = data.Results.filter(o => o.Variable === 'Error Code');
```

Just remember in this case that `errors` will hold an array and you will need to access it as such.

Answer (score 0):

By simple for loop

```
for(var i=0; i < data.Results.length;i++)
{
  if(data.Results[i].Variable == "Error Code")
  {
    console.log(data.Results[i].Value)  
    console.log(data.Results[i].ValueId)  
    console.log(data.Results[i].Variable)  
    console.log(data.Results[i].VariableId)  
  }
}
```